# How to turn ON or enable BT and Wifi at the boot time?

Tags: android

I want to turn on BT and Wifi at the system boot up from frameworks layer of AOSP.
I am changing configurations from:

frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml  :

I added network attributes for wifi and bt as:

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="networkAttributes">
    <item>"wifi,1,1,1,-1,true"</item>
    <item>"bluetooth,7,7,2,-1,true"</item>
</string-array>
```

or even tried from:

frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml

```
<resources>
    <bool name="def_bluetooth_on">true</bool>
    <bool name="def_wifi_on">true</bool>
</resources>
```

or even from made the changes from overlay directory of the device.

But both are not enable at boot time.

Are there any other changes I have to do? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

This approach worked for me on Android 7: (Replace <> accordingly)

In my device makefile (`vendor/<vendor>/products/<vendor>.mk`), I added:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS := vendor/<vendor>/overlay
```

In my `vendor/<vendor>/overlay` directory I added the File:

```
frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml
```

Content of `defaults.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="def_wifi_on">true</bool>
</resources>
```

More Info: [This Blog Post](https://medium.com/@budhdisharma/rro-runtime-resource-overlay-in-android-aosp-e094be17f4bc)

Answer (score 0):

Per default it will use the previous ON/OFF setting... 2-3 seconds after boot has completed.

This means, that this behavior clearly interferes which what you're trying to do ...

Comment: But the default parameter I made true, how will it interfere? Please elaborate.